# AWS get the file only from specific website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i'm trying guys

```html
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectVersion"],
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to have a file read only from my website and I'm not allowed to do it, I add the bucket policy but if I open the file from my site it doesn't open it, it gives me "access denied". I am using this policy, obviously i replaced with the name of my bucket and my website, but i can't figure out why it doesn't work. Do I need to add some code to my site?

Comment: Is the referer header actually sent by your browser?

Comment: @luk2302 I did not understand what you mean, my site is developed with webflow and I am trying to read the file: example a script and that it is executed / read only by my browser and if someone wants to see the source of the link (js code) it cannot. It's possible? maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Generally no. That is not possible. A referer header can simply be faked by a custom curl command. Open the console in your browser, check the request for the image and check if the referer header was sent along.

Comment: @luk2302 I don't see it honestly, it's my first time using aws. I would just have to do this and upload the files, I don't think it was of this complexity. Do I not have to enter any code on my site?

Comment: The fact that this way of protecting a file is extremely insecure has already been mentioned above. Regarding your question: Please check if your bucket is configured to block all public access. Have a look at this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html for more information.